# Show Word document on monitor from Excel vba

Tags: excel, ms-word, window, maximize, vba

My monitor shows an Excel 2013 spreadsheet, I use ALT+F8 to show the macro list, and I run one. This is the last part of the code of that macro. Briefly, I want that, conditionally on a variable named "lista" being not empty, the macro opens a Word document, writes on it the content of that variable, then my monitor should show the opened Word document, and finally the macro should stop.

```
If lista <> "" Then
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open ("\\SERVER-PDC\Archivi\DOCUMENTI SU SERVER\LAURA\pianificazione produzione\cicli mancanti.doc")
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
With objSelection.Paragraphs(1).Range
    .InsertAfter "Promemoria mancanti della settimana " & suffisso & "senza ciclo:" & Chr(13) & lista & Chr(13)
    .InsertParagraphAfter
End With
objWord.Application.Visible = True
Set objWord = Nothing
End
End If
End Sub
```

The macro opens and modifies the Word document correctly. However, at the end of the macro, my pc monitor still shows the Excel spreadsheet, and the Word document is minimized on the taskbar.

Comment: Possibly worth trying - 'ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized' at the end of the Excel document? That way the word doc should be in the foreground

Comment: I switch between Excel and ERP software many times a day, with both of them being on the background. 'ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized' returns either to Excel window or to the ERP one, I'm still working on it. At a first glance I cannot understand when it returns to ERP and when it returns to Excel, since the last window before I run the macro always is the Excel window, so I expected it always returned to .doc document, which is the last opened window after running the macro.